# Java Regex space or beginning of parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write some regex such that:

`100 pages` and `100pages`(either "100 pages match" or " 100 pages" match. The 2nd contains a space before the token "100"

`(100 pages` and `(100pages`

but not

`1100 pages`, `1,100 pages` etc.

I'm currently using Java regex.

What I've come up with is `(\s){1}(100)(\s){0,1}(pages)`

but cannot incorporate the initial parenthesis. Hopefully I can use the `|` logical operator to make my regex lean. Any suggestions?

Comment: so just `replace` white space and compare?

Comment: Hi I want to have something like `\s?\(?` but I'm not sure if this is legal.

Comment: try it out at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/qmRc88/2):

```
[\(\s]100\s?pages
```

It will first match an open parenthesis or space (`[\(\s]`), followed by `100`, followed by an optional space (`\s?`), followed by `pages`.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to match `100 pages` and `100pages` but not `1100pages` or `1,100 pages` right and you dont want the `(` in regex?

Try this https://regex101.com/r/5uOlup/1

```
(?<!\d|\d,)100\s?pages
```

Comment: Hi I want to match `(100 pages` and `(100pages` too so would like to have the left parenthesis in the regex.

Comment: Hi I want to match `(100 pages` and `(100pages` too so would like to have the left parenthesis in the regex.

Comment: ah okay so you used negative lookbehind when you did `(?<!\d|\d,)` this

Comment: yes I like to keep in my global match only the things I really need. Only when it can slow down the regex considerably i would capture groups and post treat result. Is it what you were looking for?